# Detect port connection without loosing data

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I have been trying to write a small program for Linux, to detect a client connection on a port, say 8080, and upon a connection close the socket and execvp some program.

I setup the socket for the port.
After that I do a select to wait for incoming client connections.

```
if(select(listener+1, &master, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
{
    perror("Server-select() erro!");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Close socket...\n");
close(listener);
```

After this I execvp a program, that should read then data on the port.

This all works fine, but the client which tries to connect, always fails first time, because, I guess the data send from the client to the program is lost when I close the socket.
Is there anyway to wait for port connections, without loosing the data send?
I was thinking something like not acknowledging the connection.

When I do accept() as suggested:

```
{
    struct sockaddr_in clientName = { 0 };
    int slaveSocket, clientLength = sizeof(clientName);

    (void) memset(&clientName, 0,sizeof(clientName));

    slaveSocket = accept(listener,(struct sockaddr *) &clientName,&clientLength);
    if (-1 == slaveSocket)
    {
        perror("accept()");
        exit(1);
    }
}

printf("Close socket...\n");
close(listener);

if ((child = fork()) == 0) { /* Child process. */
    printf("Child: PID of Child = %ld\n", (long) getpid());
    execvp(argv[2], &argv[2]); /* arg[0] has the command name. */
    /* If the child process reaches this point, then *//* execvp must have failed.  */
    fprintf(stderr, "Child process could not do execvp.\n");
    exit(1);
} else { /* Parent process. */
    if (child == (pid_t) (-1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        c = wait(&cstatus); /* Wait for child to complete. */
        printf("Parent: Child %ld exited with status = %d\n", (long) c,
                cstatus);
    }
}
```

The executed shell program fails with:
**bind() error (port number: 8554): Address already in use**
So I guess I need to release the port somehow?

Comment: Do you do an `accept` somewhere?

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: Why is the exec'd program doing a `bind()`? It seems to me that you're trying to do something in the master program that the exec'd program already does for itself.

Answer (score 3):

See this example how to do it correctly: http://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/linuxjournal/articles/023/2333/2333l1.html

You don't close your listening socket. You call accept to get a new fd for the incoming connection, then fork. After forking, you may close the listening socket, and use the accept'ed socket to transfer data. The parent process just closes the accepted socket and continues listening.

Answer (score 1):

As you aren't accepting the incoming connection, it must get closed when you close the listening socket. You need to call `accept()` first.